# Insert a dependent jar into an installer jar

Tags: java, maven-2, jar

I have a multi-module maven project with an installer sub-project. The installer will be distributed as an executable JAR. It will setup the DB and extract the WAR file to the app server. I would like to use maven to assemble this jar like so:

> /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
>   /com/example/installer/Installer.class
>   /com/example/installer/...
>   /server.war

The manifest will have a main-class entry pointing to the installer class. How might I get maven to build the jar in this fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build the jar using the [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

First, you'll need to add some information to your pom.xml **plugins** section to make the resulting jar executable:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>com.example.installer.Installer</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I recommend using a separate [assembly descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/using-components.html) to build the actual installer jar. Here's an example:

```
<assembly>
  <id>installer</id>

  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>

  <baseDirectory></baseDirectory>

  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <!-- this references your installer sub-project -->
        <include>com.example:installer</include>
      </includes>
      <!-- must be unpacked inside the installer jar so it can be executed -->
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
    <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <!-- this references your server.war and any other dependencies -->
        <include>com.example:server</include>
      </includes>
      <unpack>false</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

If you've saved the assembly descriptor as "installer.xml" you can build your jar by running the assembly like this:

> mvn clean package assembly:single -Ddescriptor=installer.xml

Hope this helps. Here are some additional links that you might find useful:

- [Maven Assembly Plugin - Configuration and Usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html)
- [Creating Executable JARs using the Maven Assembly Plugin](http://www.sleberknight.com/blog/sleberkn/entry/20080618)
- [Creating executable jars with Maven](http://left.subtree.org/2008/01/24/creating-executable-jars-with-maven/)